# Checking if a Birthday was between a 6 month span which crosses the year break

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-arithmetic

I am trying to write SQL code (using SQL Developer) that checks if a person had a birthday within the past 6 month insurance term.

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
SELECT DRIVER_KEY, CASE WHEN BDAY BETWEEN EFFDAY AND EXPDAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BDAYIND FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT A.DRIVER_KEY
    , TO_CHAR(A.BIRTH_DATE,'mm/dd') AS BDAY          
     , TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY,5,2)||'/'||SUBSTR(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY,7,2) ) AS EFFDAY
    , TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(A.EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY,5,2)||'/'||SUBSTR(A.EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY,7,2) ) AS EXPDAY
    FROM DRIVER_TABLE A
    );
```

It works - so long as the term doesn't cross the break in year. However, my code currently says that 01/25 is NOT between 09/19 and 03/19... How do I fix this?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question mentions a 6 month period, but your code doesn't have anything like that.

Comment: Why aren't you using the full date `mm/dd/yyyy` to determine if it falls within the range?

Comment: Since you are converting to `CHAR` or String data, `01` does not fall between `09` and `03`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** As APC pointed out, my solution does not work for leap years. I would normally delete this post, but it was already selected as the answer to the question. I updated my code below to use the year logic from Brian Leach's solution instead of the to_date strings. Please upvote Brian or APC's answers instead.

Here is my create statement with arbitrary dates:

```
create table DRIVER_TABLE
(
  BIRTH_DATE date,
  EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY date,
  EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY date
  );

  insert into DRIVER_TABLE
  values(to_date('05/01/1980','MM/DD/YYYY'),
         to_date('11/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),
         to_date('04/01/2017','MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Here is the query:

```
select case when BirthdayEFFYear between EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY and EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY 
              or BirthdayEXPYear between EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY and EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY
              or to_number(EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY - EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY) / 365 > 1
        then 1 else 0 end BDAYIND
from(
select add_months(BIRTH_DATE,12 * (extract(year from EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY) - extract(year from BIRTH_DATE))) BirthdayEFFYear,
       add_months(BIRTH_DATE,12 * (extract(year from EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY) - extract(year from BIRTH_DATE))) BirthdayEXPYear,
       EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY,EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY
from DRIVER_TABLE A
)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57043/9)

Comment: Hey! Oracle's working at SQLFiddle again? SWEET! :-)

Comment: This solution hurls if the driver is born on 29th February.

Comment: APC is right. Using this methodology, adding in a way to account for leap year would be very messy. I think APC's solution is probably the best one here to account for all cases. I just tested his and it works for leap years as well.

Answer (score 2):

Compare dates as dates, not as strings.

Apparently EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY contains the year in the first four characters, and as such the following should give you what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DRIVER_KEY,
       CASE
         WHEN BDAY BETWEEN EFFDAY AND EXPDAY THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS BDAYIND
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT A.DRIVER_KEY,
                        A.BIRTH_DATE AS BDAY,
                        TO_DATE(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD') AS EFFDAY,
                        TO_DATE(A.EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY, 'YYYYMMDD') AS EXPDAY
          FROM DRIVER_TABLE A);
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

`'01/25'` is not between `'09/19'` and `'03/19'` because `between()` is never true when the second argument is smaller than the first argument. You fall ito this trap because you're working with strings. It is always easier to work with dates using the DATE datatype.

It looks like your columns `effective_date` and `expiry_date` may not be stored as dates but rather a string; unfortunately this is a common data modelling mistake.  If so, you need to cast them to DATE first before applying the following.

This solution has a subquery which selects the pertinent columns from `driver_table` and also calculates each driver's current age in years. The age is used to derive the last birthday, which is then compared in the main query to the bounds of the insurance term. Because we derive an actual date we can use Oracle's standard date arithmetic so the `bdayind` is calculated correctly.

```
SQL> with cte as (
  2       select driver_key
  3              , date_of_birth
  4              , trunc(months_between(sysdate, date_of_birth)/12) as age
  5              , add_months(date_of_birth, 12 * (trunc(months_between(sysdate, date_of_birth)/12))) as last_birthday
  6              , effective_date
  7              , expiry_date 
  8        from driver_table
  9    )
 10  select driver_key
 11         , date_of_birth as dob
 12         , age
 13         , effective_date as eff_date
 14         , expiry_date as exp_date
 15         , last_birthday as last_bday
 16         , case 
 17              when last_birthday between effective_date and expiry_date 
 18              then 1
 19              else 0 end as bdayind
 20  from cte
 21  /   

DRIVER_KEY DOB        AGE EFF_DATE  EXP_DATE  LAST_BDAY    BDAYIND
---------- --------- ---- --------- --------- --------- ----------
        12 02-APR-98   19 01-DEC-16 31-MAY-17 02-APR-17          1
        22 02-APR-98   19 01-JAN-17 30-JUN-17 02-APR-17          1
        32 02-SEP-98   18 01-DEC-16 31-MAY-17 02-SEP-16          0
        42 02-SEP-98   18 01-JAN-17 30-JUN-17 02-SEP-16          0

SQL>
```

The subquery produces both `age` and `last_birthday` just for demonstration  purposes. In real life you only need the `last_birthday` column.

Answer (score 1):

This solution differs slightly from the others in that:

1. It works for any birthday between any effective and expiration dates
2. It accounts for leap years

The raw_data is just setting up the dates for the example:

```
    WITH
    raw_data
    AS
        (SELECT DATE '1963-08-03' AS birthday
              , DATE '2017-04-01' AS effectiveday
              , DATE '2017-10-31' AS expirationday
              , 'Billy' AS name
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE '1995-03-20' AS birthday
              , DATE '2017-04-01' AS effectiveday
              , DATE '2017-10-31' AS expirationday
              , 'Sue' AS name
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATE '1997-01-15' AS birthday
              , DATE '2016-12-01' AS effectiveday
              , DATE '2017-05-31' AS expirationday
              , 'Olga' AS name
           FROM DUAL),
    mod_data
    AS
        (SELECT raw_data.*
              , ADD_MONTHS (
                    birthday
                  , (extract(year from effectiveday) - extract (year from birthday)) * 12
                )
                    effectiveanniversary
              , ADD_MONTHS (
                    birthday
                  , (extract(year from expirationday) - extract (year from birthday)) * 12
                )
                    expirationanniversary
           FROM raw_data)
SELECT name, mod_data.birthday, effectiveday, expirationday
     , CASE
           WHEN effectiveanniversary BETWEEN effectiveday AND expirationday
             OR expirationanniversary BETWEEN effectiveday AND expirationday
           THEN
               1
           ELSE
               0
       END
           found_between
  FROM mod_data

NAME  BIRTHDAY     EFFECTIVEDAY  EXPIRATIONDAY  FOUND_BETWEEN                          
Billy 1963/08/03   2017/04/01    2017/10/31     1                                      
Sue   1995/03/20   2017/04/01    2017/10/31     0                                      
Olga  1997/01/15   2016/12/01    2017/05/31     1
```